# HTML to Excel Export with error

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am exporting created HTML and saving it to an Excel file, however; I get the error 
 `"Missing file ......css".` 
I've tried commenting out the area in the aspx that has the reference to the style sheet but I still get the same problem. I even moved all of the style from the css to the aspx file, and no improvement.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As it is, the question doesn't provide enough information for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help you or not but

I've also noticed slight variations in how excel imports in CSS and HTML depending on the version and whether its in Windows or OS X as well.

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=exported_file.xls";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
        ctl.RenderControl(htextw);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stw.ToString());
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("../Content/Styles/StyleSheet.css"));
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText();
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
        }
        sr.Close();
        Response.Write("<html><head><style type='text/css'>" + sb.ToString() + "</style></head>" + stw.ToString() + "</html>");
        stw = null;
        htextw = null;
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Comment: Let me give this a try

Comment: The object that is being used is a dataTable to hold the data.  Should that matter?